# Neural Network problems

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I am using [an external library](http://neurondotnet.freehostia.com/) for Artificial Neural Networks in my project..

While testing the ANN, It gave me output of all `NaN` (not a number in C#)

- *The ANN has 8 input , 5 hidden , 5 hidden ,  2 output, and all activation layers are of Linear type , and it uses back-propagation, with learning rate 0.65*
- *I used one testcase for training `{ -2.2, 1.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 5, 3, -5 } ,{ -0.3, 0.2 }` 
  for 1000 epoch*
- *And I tested it on `{ 0.2, -0.2, 5.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 35, 0.0 }` which gave `{ NaN , NaN}`*
  **Note:** this is one example of many that produces same case...

I am trying to discover whether it is a bug in the library, or an illogical configuration..

**The reasons I could think of for illogical configuration:**

- All layers should not be linear
- Can not have descending size layers, i.e `8-5-5-2` is bad..
- Only one testcase ?
- Values must be in range [0,1] or  [-1,1]

**Is any of the above reasons could be the cause of error, or there are some constraints/rules that I do not know in ANN designing..?**

*Note: I am newbie in ANN*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, with out knowing anything about the library you are using it is not easy to guess. Typically a ANN inputs are required to be between 0..1 or -1..1, so maybe it is because you have values outside of that range causing the unfortunate results.

If the above is the cause of the problem, there are a number of techniquest for encoding data to be passed to a ANN, for example you could scale your inputs to ensure they are always in range and maintain the relative relationship.